# laravel 5 vue.js csrf token

Tags: laravel, npm, vue.js

I've been at it for a while to get this csrf token to work with the vue.js example.

but it keeps saying i don't have a token. I've tried all kinds of variations.

bottom (not head, before end of body)

```
    <script>
    window.myToken =  <?php echo json_encode([
        '_token' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
    </script>

    <script src="/js/manifest.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

html

```
<div id="app">
@section('content')
<example></example>
@endsection
</div>
```

console output

```
CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

vendor.js:7635 You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
```

Example doesn't seem to do much either, but I guess i need the token.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you look into

> /resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

You will find

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
```

You should add in your `<head>` tag this:

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

This error will not be shown anymore.

I hope this helps

Comment: Mh doesnt seem to work for me either, also tried with csrf_token()

Comment: <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}"> into <head> works for me maybe <meta name="csrf-token" content="{!!csrf_token()!!}">

Comment: @Bas i am happy this helps you

Comment: Strange both method's don't seem to work for me, it's also in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Insert this script into your page `head` tag.

```
<script>
   window.Laravel = {
      'csrfToken' => '{{csrf_token()}}',
   };
</script>
```

In your `bootstrap.js`:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate if someone tell me ... why this is down voted ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either, i've seen that window.Laravel method before. I assume the Vue.http should also be in a script tag? I wasn't the one that downvoted though.