# CSRF token not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, csrf

I am getting this CSRF token error and when I look around everyone just said that all I need is to use {{ csrf_field() }} when I submit my data. In the past, it was working fine but after some time, I got this error and I can't submit my data or even edit my data at all. Can someone help me here thanks.

[image]

Please tell me where did I go wrong? What am I suppose to do here

edit.blade.php (this is the csrf part)

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id) }}">

          {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
          {{ csrf_field() }}

         <div class="input-group">
            <label><b>Name/NRIC:</b></label>
              <input type="text" name="Name" value="{{ $object->Name }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
</form>
```

app.js (laravel default not mine, this is what I saw)

```
/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = __webpack_require__(16);

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

var token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
  console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

**EDIT:**
Not sure if this is related but since it is the login part just want to know if it affects this.

I have actually 2 app.blade.php for the layout so was wondering is that the reason which is causing this whole problems?

Comment: Please show the related code.

Comment: Is it an Ajax call ??

Comment: Ajax call? Sorry what do you mean by that, I just do it normally based on what I saw on tutorial videos and from documents @Maraboc

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I have updated the question with my code that I think is related

Comment: i mean via javaScript, so it's not ajax then :)

Comment: @Muraboc yup no javascript used, the app.js is based from the laravel application itself if I am not wrong and I didn't really touch it

Comment: @Dkna you're loading some JS built with Mix. Please show the `app.js` or something.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin but I didn't use the app.js, it was already there when I first started using laravel and I didn't even touch it. And if I would want to show, could you tell me which part should I show? There is like a lot of lines of code in there, I have updated the question could you take a look if it is what you were looking for?

Comment: In the end it's javaScript :p so Ajax call ;)

Comment: @Maraboc javascript? But I didn't use it at all, sorry I am quite unsure what is going on right now, do you mean because of the app.js?

Comment: @Maraboc I have updated the question and wonder could that be one of the cause?

Comment: So add the `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token}}">` in the two headers of the the two blades !

Comment: @Maraboc it is already there by default

Comment: can you add the submit button code ? and the top of the view code ?

Comment: For the login part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162874/discussion-between-maraboc-and-dkna).

Comment: What happens if you run `document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')` in the console when viewing your page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix CSRF token not found on console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603815/how-to-fix-csrf-token-not-found-on-console)

Answer (score 5):

Go to your master blade or `app.blade.php` and make sure you add this :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: are you extending that blade

Comment: Yup, in every blade page I used something like this, @extends('layouts.app')

Comment: Hi I have updated the question, and would like to know if that could be the cause

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me too; it might be due to some Laravel update. Can't say for sure if the line was there, or not, prior to 5.8.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add this into your head tag

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token}}">
```

this error will not be shown anymore.

for more details go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988755/laravel-5-vue-js-csrf-token/44988898#44988898) for more details

Comment: @Dkna https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988755/laravel-5-vue-js-csrf-token/44988898#44988898 look at my answer here

Comment: Yup I saw it and it is exactly what you said, I have followed that already. I checked that if it is at the head tag and it is. This was the default layout laravel gave when I used the authentication and I didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Start and end of your form

```
{!!
    Form::
    open(
    array(
    'id'=>'FormIF',
    'name'=>'FormName',
    'autocomplete'=>'off' ,
    'url' =>route('route_to_post_method')
    )
    )
    !!}

//Form Body

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Just asking then where do I put the action and method part of the form?

Comment: url for action and method not needed. It default uses POST

Comment: just check html of your form via browser and see if something like <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="u0erOF5UHhRxyFJ2l9tJ3RlvrWVysPBGEGdd7M8q"> is there or not

Answer (score 0):

open your inspector and make sure the meta tag is placed in head .
if you find meta placed in body , so you may include script out of section field in your section script, you must include into section field.

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
@include('sidebar')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to check your generated HTML file `ctrl+U`. You will notice that your HTML `<head>` tag is probably placed inside of the body tag. This happens if you don't get your **layout** and **blade** sections right.

This happened to me before

```
@extends('layouts.main-layout')
  <h1>Laravel Project</h1> <--This will break the **generated template**
@section('content')
    <div id="app"></div>
@endsection
```

The `<h1>` will break template you will see the **CSRF-token** error in the console.